# Video is not playing in lightbox

Tags: video, html5-video, lightbox, lightbox2

I have mixed content like images and videos.How can i show and play a video.

I am trying to show and play a video but there is a loading going on nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lightbox2` does not support to show videos within the lightbox and this is not planned as they stated in their roadmap: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/ROADMAP.md

> The goal of this script from it's beginnings till today is to to provide a better image viewing experience.

> HTML or video content: If you need to show html or video content, I recommend googling for an alternative script as there are many options.